# Powershell script to count files in a single folder and output count to a log file if the files exceed a set number

Tags: powershell

'I need this to loop every 20 seconds for about 14 hours a day.  This is what I have so far, but I am having some issues with the loop and output.'

```
        $timeout = New-TimeSpan -Hours 14
        $sw = [diagnostics.stopwatch]::StartNew()
        $count = (Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\folder' | Measure-Object).count
     
        <# Loop condition check every 20 seconds until timeout #>
        While ($sw.elapsed -lt $timeout){
        If ($count -gt 30)
        {
        "$([datetime]::Now) $count" | Out-File C:\temp\file_count.log -Append
        }
        start-sleep -Seconds 20
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What issues are you facing with your current code exactly?  Read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so we can better answer your question.

Comment: You are not showing or explaining what your issues are. As written, this just writes the count of files in the folder to a log file every 20 seconds. As written, this should be working. You just end up with around 40+ entries per day via this check.

Comment: @michielThai is correct, you need to perform the count **inside** the while loop.Also add switch `-File` to the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet if you only want to count the number of **files** and not directories too.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that your count of filer is only done once, outside your `while` loop.
Move the `$Count =`  right under the `while` statement, and I think your issue is solved